# Using PHP to dynamically create pages from a template

Tags: php

I'm creating a blog for a website I am building. The main blog page obviously has each blog listed as it should. But I want each blog to also have it's own individual page on the website. I want this page to be generated on creation of the blog post.

My question is, what would be the best method of creating this page. If I use the php file functions to create it, I would need to fill up a $data variable with hundreds of lines of HTML for the page. Which I guess is feasible, IF I am also able to dynamically change the variable to work for the new content that needs to be posted on said page.

Is there better methods? Would PHP work for this? Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Yes, it's called [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) :)

Comment: That is one of php's main purposes. If you weren't using a platform like wordpress (which you should - because why reinvent the wheel?) then you would build the elements that don't change (like the header and footer), then call them using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php?) to build the page. You would be best to then store everything in a database and call the content... but as already mentioned, there's a million frameworks for this - one of which is called [wordpress](http://wordpress.org)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions guys. Unfortunately if I was looking to simply click a few buttons and create a wordpress related site, I would have already done this. Rather, i'm looking to simply expand my knowledge of coding, and i'm looking for suggestions on how to do this through StackOverflow, which was designed to do just that. But again, thank you for at least commenting.

Comment: @Josh We may seem heartless but a blog is not a child's play. *When you code a blog, the question you have just asked here should not exist for you.* You are supposed to know how PHP works, includes, templating, replacing string, regular expressions and such. Also translating a dynamic address into a database table row that represents a post... and such. And I'm not even scratching the surface...

Comment: use worpress, simple and best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would do it more or less like this:

**1. Create a 'Blogs' SQL database table.**
Create an 'id' column (primary key), and columns for fields like 'blog_date', 'title', 'author', and 'html_content'.

**2. Create a 'Blog' class using php.**
Create properties which correspond to the SQL fields in your 'Blogs' table, including 'id'.

**3. Create public 'loadFromDB()' and 'saveToDB()' methods**
These methods should load and save the SQL values of a row in 'Blogs' (selected by id) to and from the class properties.

**4. Create a public 'view()' method for the 'Blog' class**
This is simply an HTML view/template of a single blog entry displaying date, title, author, etc.

**5. Create an 'index.php' blog page in a folder on the server**
You want to use this page to display a single blog entry.
Use a blog's SQL id when calling this page from links in your main blogs page, for example via http GET: 'http://www.yoursite.com/blogs/blog/index.php?id=30'.  In your php code inside index.php, where you want the entry to appear, do something like this:

```
$id_default = 27;  // the blog entry which must appear when there is no query parameter
$id = empty($_GET['id']) ? $id_default : $_GET['id'];
$B = new Blog($id);
$B->loadFromDB();
$html = $B->view();
echo $html;
```

In this way, you don't have to create an HTML page for EVERY blog entry, or put ALL the entries on one page.  You can just use one page created dynamically with a GET parameter instead.

Obviously there is more you can/must do, such as creating commenting displays and forms and a 'Comments' SQL table, etc.  But this should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to create individual page for each blog dynamically. Here are the steps you can follow.

1. Create one master template. Add some special tags where you want dynamic content.
2. While adding new post, Read the content from that master template, replace appropriate special tags with actual values
3. Write finally generated content into new file and save it to associated location.
4. You are ready to access that page.